# Undefined method `shift' for "b":String (NoMethodError) Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I keep getting the same error when trying to run this method that translates a string into pig latin.

```
def pig_latin_word(word)
  new_arr = []
  letter = word.split("")

    if letter[0] == "a" || letter[0] == "e" || letter[0] == "i" || letter[0] == "o" || 
      letter[0] == "u"
      new_arr << "yay"
    else
      letter[0].shift && new_arr << letter[0].push + "ay"
    end
  return new_arr.join
end
```

---

```
# Test cases: 
puts pig_latin_word("eat")     # => "eatyay"
puts pig_latin_word("banana")  # => "ananabay"
puts pig_latin_word("trash")   # => "ashtray"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#shift` and `#push` are both array methods and you're calling them on `letter[0]` which is a string. 
Even if you fixed this to use `letter.shift` and `letter.push` you're still not going to get "trash" => "ashtray" unless you loop and gather the constants from the beginning of the word.

```
def pig_latin_word(word)
  exp = /^[AEIOUaeiou]/
  if word =~ exp
    word + "yay"
  else
    word.each_char
        .take_while {|c| c !~ exp }
        .yield_self do |consonants|
          word[consonants.length..-1] + consonants.join + "ay"
        end
  end
end
```

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class PigLatinTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_word_that_begins_with_a_vowel
    assert_equal("eatyay", pig_latin_word("eat"))
  end
  def test_word_that_begins_with_a_consonant
    assert_equal("ananabay", pig_latin_word("banana"))
  end
  def test_word_that_begins_with_multiple_consonants
    assert_equal("ashtray", pig_latin_word("trash"))
  end
end
```

```
maxcal@pop-os ~/p/sandbox> ruby test.rb
Run options: --seed 59131

# Running:

...

Finished in 0.001205s, 2488.6889 runs/s, 2488.6889 assertions/s.
3 runs, 3 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

See:

- [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/String.html#method-i-each_char)
- [Enumerable#take_while](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while)
- [yield_self](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2017/12/12/ruby-2-5-added-yield_self.html)

Answer (score 2):

from what I see you are trying to do a shift to a letter (String).  Essentially whenever you do a letter[0].shift you are dereferencing the first element of the array which is a string. Shift works with arrays.

Here is a code snippet that does exatly what you try to do. Only the last test case could not return the value you suggest given the code you post. You say it shoud return "ashtray", but if you shift away the first letter, attach it to the last and add ay you should actually get "rashtay"

```
def pig_latin_word(word)
  return "#{word}yay" if word =~ /^[AEIOUaeiou]/
  word_array = word.split('')
  latin_word = "#{word_array[0..word_array.length].join}#{word_array.shift}ay"

  return latin_word
end

puts pig_latin_word("eat")     # => "eatyay"
puts pig_latin_word("banana")  # => "ananabay"
puts pig_latin_word("trash")   # => "rashtay"
```

Comment: return is implicit in ruby and there is no point in assigning `latin_word = "#{word_array[0..word_array.length].join}#{word_array.shift}ay"` if the local variable is never used.

Comment: Yes, that is correct about return. It is just a habbit I have from other languages. Besides at least for me it is kind of more readable. As for the assignment - you are quite correct about that too :)

Comment: Explicit return is regarded as bad style. https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#no-explicit-return

Comment: How about the escape calause. One could argue how much use there is for one here, but if you have some larger block of code a return for an escape clause would actually shorten exectution time. In the code above it does not execute below the first line if it matches the regular expression.

Comment: thats ok. But if you add return to the last line of a method in ruby you look like a noob.